# Basic issue retrieve array or string from file using Storable retrieve

Tags: perl, storable

The problem is very simple but I can't seem to find it:

I store a `$string` to a `$filename`:

`store [$tempstring], $filename2[$m];`

I then try to retrieve it:

`my $tempinput = retrieve ($filename2[$m]);`

I believe I'm just getting the reference, not the string?
Can I use a command to convert the data back to the original string?

Comment: Ok, confirmed this sample code works:                       #!/opt/perl/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;


use Storable;

my @a = (1, 2, 3);

store(\@a, "array.dat");

my @a2 = @{retrieve("array.dat")};

print "The value is: $a2[1]";

Comment: unless you are sure you will never retrieve on a different computer or even OS version, use nstore, not store.

Comment: Why do you need Storable if all you need to store is a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 my $ref = [ $tempstring ];
```

creates an array, assigns `$tempstring` to it (placing it in the first element), then returns a reference to that array.

So if you want the string back, you need to get the value of the first element of the referenced array.

```
 $ref->[0]
```

---

If you had done

```
 my $ref = \$tempstring;
```

instead of needlessly creating an array, you'd simply do

```
 $$ref
```

to get the string.

Comment: Please signal this by checking the mark next to the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Here's what I did to store the string and then retrieve it:          my $ref = [ $tempstring ];
store($ref, $filename2[$m]); my @a2 = @{retrieve($filename2[$m])};